# Is there a way to automatically split large clusters that are greater than some maximum number of points?

Tags: python, clustering, spatial, dbscan

I ran HDBSCAN on these coordinates and got some clusters but some are too large. HDBSCAN has a minimum cluster size parameter, but no maximum size. All I want is to intuitively divide larger clusters so that none are larger than a maximum cluster size. Essentially, something that creates the second plot below. I could rerun HDBSCAN on the cluster, but it isn't guaranteed to reduce the size. I can do k-means, but I'm using clustering on a shortest-path distance matrix, something that I don't think k-means can handle.

[image]

````
mins = 40
min_size = 400

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=min_size, min_samples=mins, allow_single_cluster=True) 
clusterer.fit(df.iloc[:, 0:2])
pd.Series(clusterer.labels_).value_counts()

df['cluster'] = clusterer.labels_
df['subcluster'] = np.nan

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

unique_labels = np.unique(clusterer.labels_)
noise_data = df[df['cluster'] == -1]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,6)) # Create 1 row, 2 columns of plots

for label in unique_labels:
    subset = df[df['cluster'] == label]
    if label == -1:
        ax[0].scatter(subset[0], subset[1], label="Noise", color='gray', marker=".", alpha=0.3)
    else:
        ax[0].scatter(subset[0], subset[1], label=f'Cluster {label}', marker = ".", alpha=1)

ax[0].set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax[0].set_title('Clusters')
ax[0].legend() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe [agglomerative clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) is what you are looking for.

You can set the *affinity* attribute to "precomputed" to use your shortest-path distance matrix.

And then you can set the *distance_threshold* manually after inspecting the dendrogram to obtain the desired cluster sizes.